# Не получается подтянуть проект по тэгу в go

Tags: golang, модули, git-tag

Проект, который я пытаюсь стянуть имеет в go.mod первой строчкой следующие:

```
module gitlab.com/path/v3
```

Внутри проекта везде также указаны ссылки на v3. И на последний коммит установлен тег v3.0.0-beta.

Во втором проекте, в который я пытаюсь стенуть первый по выше указаному тегу, я получаю следующие:

```
go list -m: gitlab.com/path/v3@v3.0.0-beta: invalid version: go.mod has non-.../v3 module path "gitlab.com/path/v2" (and .../v3/go.mod does not exist) at revision v3.0.0-beta
go list -m: gitlab.com/path/v3@v3.0.0-beta: go.mod has non-.../v3 module path "gitlab.com/path/v2" (and .../v3/go.mod does not exist) at revision v3.0.0-beta
```

В чем дело? И как мне это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась с помощью очистки кэша:

```
go clean -modcache
go mod tidy
```